# NullPointerException at SerializationFilter

Tags: blazeds

I am setting up BlazeDS on a Coldfusion server, and I am trying to get a simple chat interface to show up.  The setup involves creating a gateway in coldfusion administrator, then hitting it with a simple Flex chatroom.  I have tested it locally on my own computer, and it works.  So I did the same thing on the server.  I tested the gateway, and it seems to work.  However, when I try to hit it with the Flex code externally, I get the following error..

```
12/28 15:01:11 Information [scheduler-0] - Run Client Storage Purge
[BlazeDS]null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SerializationFilter.deserializationError
(SerializationFilter.java:236)
        at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SerializationFilter.invoke(Serialization
Filter.java:130)
        at flex.messaging.endpoints.BaseHTTPEndpoint.service(BaseHTTPEndpoint.ja
va:278)
        at coldfusion.flash.messaging.CFAMFEndPoint.service(CFAMFEndPoint.java:2
95)
        at flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet.service(MessageBrokerServlet.java
:322)
        at coldfusion.flex.ColdFusionMessageBrokerServlet.service(ColdFusionMess
ageBrokerServlet.java:114)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
        at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:8
9)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
        at coldfusion.filter.FlashRequestControlFilter.doFilter(FlashRequestCont
rolFilter.java:71)
        at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46
)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
        at jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
        at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
        at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
        at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:
286)
        at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:
543)
        at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.ja
va:203)
        at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.j
ava:428)
        at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

What does this error mean and what would be the likely solution?

Comment: did you ever figure out what the problem was with this?